# CoreData - Xcode 5 - M:N relation

Tags: core-data, relationship, data-modeling

I have simple Data mode. Model has 3 tables: **teacher,class, teacher_class**. **Teacher** can teach more **classes** and **class** can have more **teachers**.It's classic M:N problem. So, I did third table **class_teacher**, which represents couple **teacher-class**. The third class has 2 foreign key (FK) teacher and class. The Data model is here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/41jr1h713scgxyj/Screenshot%202014-03-03%2021.50.21.png

Please, how can I represent this model in CoreData. In CoreData isn't any FK or PK so, how I can model the relationship? Only with two tables, which have relantionship many to many?? It is possible? Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, create 2 entities and create a bi-directional many to many relationship (create a relationship in each direction and set them as inverse of each other). In this way a Teacher can have a relationship to any number of Classes and vice-versa. You do not need a third entity.

You can add an index in Core Data if you need one, it is added to an attribute of your choice by ticking the `indexed` option in Xcode.

Comment: Wain, please. When I have two tables: 1:1 for example table num.1: "Teacher", table num.2 : "Address". I have to insert in table Teachers a attribute address (Foreign key) or it isn't necessary. And when I have relation M:N for example Teachers and Classes how I can detect the concrete couples, when I haven't FKs in any tables for example: Mr.Brown teaches 4.A and Mr.Brown teaches 5.A and Ms. Smith teaches 4.A too. What will look such a record in the tables? Sorry, but I have fixated logic from data model and here is it different. Thank you.

Comment: You need to stop thinking about tables and foreign keys and start thinking about objects and relationships (sets of pointers to other objects).

Answer (score 3):

Didn't follow your link.  Also, when asking a question, you should be explicit, and not assume readers know what things like `FK` and `PK` mean.

As for your model, you can do it easily enough with a multiway relationship.

In the model GUI, you add a relationship to `teacher` that references `class` and you set each side of the relationship to be 'to many'.  Thus, each instance of `teacher` can have multiple `class` relationships and each instance of `class` can have multiple `teacher` relationships.

Comment: FK = Foreign key, PK = Primary key

Comment: I am sure you mean "set each side of the relationship type to be 'to many'". Unlimited is not something you define in the model.  It defaults to "unbounded" which is most likely what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra Thanks.  I've been building a lot of models in code and, I've come to call setting both `minCount` and `maxCount` as unlimited.  Probably should be a bit more careful.